# Having trouble with layout.jade and linking to top-menu.jade

Tags: html, express, pug

I am using express for my latest project.  I've never used jade before, so I'm trying to understand why I'm having issue or if I'm just going about this the wrong way.

Here is what's in my layout.jade:

```
doctype html

html
  head
    title The Outpost
    meta(charset='utf-8')
    meta(name='viewport', content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0')
    link(href='stylesheets/style.css', rel='stylesheet')
    link(href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css", rel="stylesheet")
    link(href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css', rel='stylesheet')
  body
    block top-menu
```

I have another file called top-menu.jade with the following:

```
extends layout

block top-menu
  <!-- menu code -->
```

Unfortunately, nothing shows up even if I replace something in the commented section with something like `<p>hello</p>`

Please let me know.

Comment: Try to rename your block according to camelCase notation: `topMenu`

Comment: Works fine for me (using `jade@1.11.0`). Are you calling `res.render('layout')` instead of `res.render('top-menu')` by any chance?

Comment: Thanks that was the issue.  I changed how I am calling it and now it works :)